# Get like values with groupBy

Tags: laravel, group-by, collections, having

I have a users table with the following records:

[image]

From the above records, i want to fetch only users with like names.

My expected result is to get users with like names as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

So, this is what I've tried:

```
$users = User::groupBy('name')->having(DB::raw('count(*)'), ">", "1")->select('name')->get();

dd($clients);
```

But this is the result I was getting:

[image]

I want to able to get the users with like names.

Answer (score 0):

I do think this should work in your case:

```php
    User::query()
        ->select('name')
        ->having(DB::raw('count(name)'), '>', 2)
        ->groupBy('name')
        ->get();
```

UPD:

```php
    $value = sprintf('%%%s%%', 'test');
    return User::query()
        ->select('name')
        ->where('name', 'like', $value)
        ->having(DB::raw('count(name)'), '>', 2)
        ->groupBy('name')
        ->get();
```

Comment: This only works where the names are the same.

But in my case, the names are alike.

Comment: I`ve updated my suggestion

Comment: This didn't work still.
The $value needs to be the gotten from the table, not hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

```
    User::query()
   ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$searchTerm}%") 
   ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%{$searchTerm}%") 
   ->get();
```

This will return all records that have a name or email that contains the string in $searchTerm.

So in your case, you might need to add a groupBy statement too.

You can find more details in [this](https://freek.dev/1182-searching-models-using-a-where-like-query-in-laravel) link